# Mockwebserver shutdown failed

Tags: okhttp, mockwebserver

I am getting this error **java.io.ioexception gave up waiting for executor to shut down** when I do mockwebserver.shutdown(). I can see in the debug trace that the server has few active threads which is causing the error. Is there a way to check and wait upon the active threads?